# kup-04040 when accessing external table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I set up an external table in an Oracle directory. The database instance is 12.1.0.2.0, the operating system is an Oracle Linux.

I created the physical directory under /home/oracle as the oracle user. I created the Oracle directory as sys and granted all on the directory to the schema user. Then I copied the file "bmw.csv" to the directory, the file is owned by the oracle user.

The code for the table:

```
create table ext_csv_arlista (
    Parts_number varchar2(50),
    New_Parts_number varchar2(50),
    Description varchar2(100),
    DE_List_price number(8,2),
    Discount_Group varchar2(10),
    Purchase_price number(8,2),
    BE_sales_price  number(8,2)
    )
    organization external 
    (
         default directory GENCARPARTS_CSV 
            access parameters
         (
             records delimited by newline
                BADFILE 'ext_csv_arlista.bad'
                DISCARDFILE 'ext_csv_arlista.discard'
                LOGFILE 'ext_csv_arlista.log'
             skip 1
             fields terminated by ';'         )
         location ('bmw.csv')
     );
```

When I try to select from the table:

```
select * from ext_csv_arlista
```

I get

ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file bmw.csv in GENCARPARTS_CSV not found

I get the same result if I "touch" a file and try to read from the empty file.

Oracle creates the log file, which contains:

LOG file opened at 03/21/17 22:41:29

KUP-05004:   Warning: Intra source concurrency disabled because parallel select was not requested.

KUP-04040: file bmw.csv in GENCARPARTS_CSV not found

This whole thing escapes me, the log file is there which for me means that the path is correct, oracle can write the directory.

ls -l:

```
[oracle@csuka g2]$ ls -l
total 25884
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall 26499791 Mar 21 16:17 bmw.csv
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle dba          1940 Mar 21 22:41 ext_csv_arlista.log
[oracle@csuka g2]$
```

To verify I tried to access the file with utl_file>

```
declare
    v_h utl_file.file_type;
    v_l varchar2(600);
begin
    v_h:=utl_file.fopen(LOCATION => 'GENCARPARTS_CSV', FILENAME => 'bmw.csv', OPEN_MODE => 'r');
    for v_i in 1..5
    loop
        utl_file.get_line (v_h,v_l);
        dbms_output.put_line (v_l);
    end loop;
    utl_file.fclose(v_h);
end;
```

The utl_file succeeds without problems.

What am I missing?

Cheers

Krisztian

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have no idea why it works that way but I recreated the directory as root

```
mkdir /g2
chwown oracle:dba /g2
chmod 777 /g2

su - oracle

cp /home/oracle/g2/bmw.csv /g2
```

maybe it has something to do with how /home/oracle is set up. What made this really weird is the utl_file worked perfectly, the log file could be created, etc....

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, and it was because of a foolish mistake. I was connected to an external database, so the database wasn't on my own machine. But the directory and the file were on my machine. Maybe you also have such kind of problem? So make sure that the system under the database has direct access to your external table file.